# Insert a value in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, iframe

I've got this structure and I want to change the values of the form based on the form before. Problem is, the iframe got no ID and I can't set one as it is a plugin that retrieves the data from another domain.

```
    ...<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('betterplace').style.display='block';
              var betterplace = document.getElementById('betterplace')[0];betterplace.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].document.getElementById('donation_presenter_address_first_name').value=document.getElementById('_vorname').value;
                 " style="border:none; height: 50px; width: 250px; font-weight:bold; font-size: 14pt; background-color:#94C119;color:white;cursor: pointer;" value="Ihre Spende abschlie&szlig;en"/>



    <div id="betterplace" style="display:none;">
                <div style="width:500px;height:2px;margin-bottom:5px;background-color: #94c119"/>
                <br/>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will call the frame:

```
parent.frames[1].doWhatEver
```

All frames are put into an array, the first frame of your site will be `parent.frames[0]`, the second `parent.frames[1]` and so on.

**Edit:**

If this does not work, you can always use this method:

```
parent.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].doWhatEver
// or
parent.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].doWhatEver
```

`getElementsByTagName(tagName)` returns an array with elements that have the `tagName` (e.g. `<iframe>`). With this you can get your frame.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand your problem but if you want to insert some text or html into the iframe you can do this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your iframe id') // if the iframe is already exists
    doc, div;

doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('some text') // if you want to write to the iframe
doc.close();

div = doc.createElement('div');
// this div will appear in iframe

doc.body.appendChild(div)
```

Note: you can only manipulate iframe content if the iframe domain is the **same** as the domain of the main page

**An example of  dynamic creation of iframe:**

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
    doc, div;
iframe.src = '' // same domain as main page

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('some text') // if you want to write to the iframe
doc.close();

div = doc.createElement('div');
// this div will appear in iframe
div.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('im a div inside the iframe'));
doc.body.appendChild(div);
```

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abforce/hX73W/)

Answer (score -1):

If it got no ID you have to draw it DOM path just analyze the path and get it in either JavaScript or JQUERY